# DataGridView to Excel - numbers saved as text

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I have a VB.Net form that lets me save a `DataGridView` as Excel, but it saves the numbers as text. That means that the pie charts and stuff don't "refresh".
Should I format the columns with numbers in the VB code or is there another way to save numbers as numbers?

Once I used an Excel template, where the `DataGridView` values go to an existing file. I thought that they would be formatted the way the cells were formatted.

This is part of the code I'm using.

```
Private Sub ButtonExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExport.Click
    Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)
    Dim xlPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "template.xlsx")

    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("data")

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 4) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value
            Next
        Next
    Next 
    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\User\Desktop\" & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    Me.Close()
    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
End Sub
```

I already tried `DataGridView1.Columns(2).ValueType = GetType(Decimal)` but it does nothing.

Comment: It looks like you're opening an existing workbook with a sheet named "data".  Are the cells formatted as number in that sheet?

Formatting the column could be interesting (though I see that failed) - have you tried formatting each cell (in column 2) as you add the value?  Each cell can have it's own format so maybe something is preventing the column-level assignment from working because the cells already exist.

Comment: at first i thought it would work. i failed lol. nope i didn't try that. you mean somthing like `xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 4) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.type(decimal)`?

Comment: @SteveBarron i don't find a way to implement that. everytime i write "decimal" it goes to "of decimal" .. so i'm using the wrong syntax. ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered by the OP, again :D

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
   For j = 0 To DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1
     Dim val As Object = DataGridView2(2, i).Value
        If IsDBNull(val) Then
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3) = Nothing
        Else
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3) = CDbl(val)
      End If
   Next
Next
```