# Storing numeric values in an Excel sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

I am facing a problem when saving numerical values in an Excel sheet. When I do an insert or update query that involves numerical values, VB.NET transfers to the sheet as if they were text ... which I do not want that. The cell that I insert the number with vb.net is highlighted with a green box indicating that the value is stored as text and not as a number:

[image]

I tried to insert as a number with the following line but still keep it as such:

```
comando.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Val(dato)
```

How could make vb.net save it as number and not as Text?

EDIT: Someone mark my question as a possible duplicate. The other linked question use COM/INTEROP... Im not using that, Im working full with OLE DB. I just want to know if there is any way to store a number on an Excel without saving it as text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507284/datagridview-to-excel-numbers-saved-as-text :)

Comment: You are using `Val`. There is a rarely ever a reason to do so. What happens without `Val`?

Comment: @Jeroen Nothing... same problem

Comment: I think the mistake you are making is assuming your data going in is cleanly numeric. Obviously Excel has a different opinion about this.

Comment: In the Excel file, I defined the column as numerical .... in theory there should be no problems because the value thats I'm going to insert/update it is a number ... but Excel still want to save as text...

Comment: Like I said, Excel (and or OleDb) disagrees with your assessment what a number is. You can argue it all you want, unless you work on the Excel (and or OleDb) development team, you have to live with it. Excel doesn't think it's a number. I would take a long hard look at the data you are trying to insert. Something we cannot do for you, because we can only see one line of your code, the line that you think is important, but for all we know you variable named `dato` contains the blood of Mickey Mouse.

Comment: If you SELECT from the worksheet, you could look at the DataColumn datatype.  If that sheet has that column set as text, you cant do anything about it

Comment: As mentioned several times already, it seems that the problem has to do with the data you are trying to insert as a number and not within excel. Just have a look at the number in the line above the one with 12 as text, it contains a value of 43 which was recognized by excel as a number. Therefore, strongly suggest to check thoroughly the source data and identify the difference between both values; that will give you an idea of the real problem.

Comment: I often have similar problems with numeric and date formats in Excel and it is often tricky to solve it. When Excel identifies text where I want decimal value I execute code that corrects the cell by setting Value2 and Format properties of the cell. BTW. I do not see insert/update code in your question. I see only one line of code that sets a parameter of a query. How do you execute the query?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try formatting the cells

```
 Dim formatRange As Excel.Range
 formatRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("a1", "b1")
 formatRange.NumberFormat = "#,###,###"
 xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "1234567890"
```

or

```
 Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim temp As String
 temp = "B" & (VariableYouAreEntering.Count + 1)
 With shXL.Range("B1", temp)
    .NumberFormat = "000000" 'or however you want to format it
 End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that Im working without COM....

Comment: Is it a problem to access Excel just to format the cells? Because if what you are entering is truly a number, Excel still might not think that it is. But if you format the cells you are telling Excel what format it is meant to be. But other than that I'm not sure how to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert to double:

```
CDbl(vaL(dato))
```

or just `CDbl(dato)` - after comment suggestion.

Here be the link: [Convert String to Double - VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172306/convert-string-to-double-vb) There are other ways you may try.

Comment: The Val isn't needed in `CDbl(Val(dato))`

Comment: :-D `Val` is rarely a good idea, @Cal-cium. However, we really don't know what is in the `dato` variable.... Hence, me suggestion to have a long hard look at the data going from VB to Excel.

Comment: @Jeroen i only suggested as wouldn't `CDbl(Val(dato))`  be converting to a number and then converting to a double, seems like val was needless conversion in this line as your only converting it again, though i suppose it doesn't hurt to have it in.

Comment: @Cal-cium Val has some really funny side effects. Anyway, it can be used to strip the "stringy" bits out of a string. So if you have something like "123 East 11th Street" Val will give you 12311. I have no clue why that would ever be what you'd want but there it is :-D

Comment: Actually that's wrong... `Val("123 East 11th Street")` will return 123. `Val("123 11th Street")` will return 12311. It will give up at the first non-numeric character, but happily ignores spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

```
Dim dato As String = "123.45" 
Dim value As Double

If Double.TryParse(dato, value) Then
    comando.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = value
Else
    comando.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = 0
End If
```

Also, I would try comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", value)

Would you share your comando CommandText with us?